# C# - Detect Obfuscator

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

Straight to my Question: How should I go about viewing the classes of a assembly. (.exe, dll) And if the selected program contains the class name, write to the console "Class " + Classfound + " found!" What I'm doing is, I'm making a Console Application that detects the Obfuscator used on the selected executable/dll file. I have taken the time to look through the internet, for how to reflect some classes etc but I have found nothing.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

there are many ways to detect obfuscator - mostly sum's up to Entropy&Anomaly in the project OR signatures for specific packers.

check this (open source) for some leads:
https://github.com/0xd4d/de4dot

Quote:

### Detect obfuscator

```
Use the -d option to detect the obfuscator without deobfuscating any assembly.

Find all .NET assemblies and detect obfuscator. If it's an unsupported obfuscator or if it's not obfuscated, it will print "Unknown obfuscator".

de4dot -d -r c:\input
Same as above except that it will only show which files have been obfuscated by a supported obfuscator.

de4dot -d -r c:\input -ru
Detect obfuscator

de4dot -d file1.dll file2.dll file3.dll
```